# How to split a file on a particular pattern in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, sed, split

I have a requirement where I have to split a file at an underscore pattern and the result should be grouped.

For eg,

My file contains,

```
ADD1_5001AB
ADD1_5002AB
ADD1_5003BC
ADD2_5100XY
ADD2_5101YZ
CANC1_5200AB
CANC1_5201BC
CANC2_5301GH
CANC2_5302FG
```

so my result should have 4 files,
1st file should contain ,

```
ADD1_5001AB
ADD1_5002AB
ADD1_5003BC
```

2nd file should contain,

```
ADD2_5100XY
ADD2_5101YZ
```

3rd file should contain,

```
CANC1_5200AB
CANC1_5201BC
```

4th file should contain,

```
CANC2_5301GH
CANC2_5302FG
```

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk is a good solution for this:

```
awk -F"_" '{print $0 > $1}' infile.txt
```

That will split by underscore (`-F"_"`), and print each line (`print $0`) to a file named after the bit before the underscore (`> $1`).

Comment: Thanks a ton JNevill, it's working exactly how I wanted.

Comment: I have another problem. Can you also help me in splitting the same file based on line number, I.e after it gets split at the underscore then it has to be again split at a line number. In the same awk command

Comment: Please ask a new question